# How can i load proxies from a txt file in python?

Tags: python, http, get, python-requests, proxies

How can i load proxies from a txt file in python?

The proxies are the following format:

```
1.1.1.1:80
1.1.1.2:80
```

All of them are open on port 80.

Here is what i tried but without success it only gets 1 proxy from the file for some reasons.

```
import requests

s = requests.session()
proxy = set()
with open("proxies.txt", "r") as f:
    file_lines1 = f.readlines()
    for line1 in file_lines1:
        proxy.add(line1.strip())
        
proxies = {
    'http': 'http://'+line1
    }


r = requests.get('http://www.google.com/',proxies=proxies)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `proxy` variable that contains all the proxies. You can use the random module to pick random proxies

```
import requests, random

s = requests.session()
proxy = set()

with open("proxies.txt", "r") as f:
    file_lines1 = f.readlines()
    for line1 in file_lines1:
        proxy.add(line1.strip())
        
proxies = {
    'http': 'http://'+random.choice(list(proxy))
}


r = requests.get('http://www.google.com/',proxies=proxies)
```

Comment: So when using multi threading and making requests it is gonna use 1 proxy/req? `def request() url='http://www.google.com/' req = request.get(url,proxies=proxies)`

Comment: `proxy` variable can be shared between the threads. `random.choice` gives one element that is picked randomly

Comment: Do you have any ideeas how can i do that? to use proxies/threads?

Comment: You can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280094/python-requests-with-multithreading

Comment: Thanks I was looking for this kind of solution