# Python for loop API request

Tags: python, api, for-loop

I am extracting data [from this API](https://financialmodelingprep.com/developer/docs/)
I was able to save the JSON file on my local machine.
I want to run the requests for several stocks.
How do I do it?
I tried to play with for loops but not good came out of this. I attached the code below.
the out put is:

```
AAPL
[]
TSLA
[]
```

Thank you, Tal

```
try:
# For Python 3.0 and later
from urllib.request import urlopen
except ImportError:
# Fall back to Python 2's urllib2
from urllib2 import urlopen
import requests
import json
import time


def get_jsonparsed_data(url):
"""
Receive the content of ``url``, parse it as JSON and return the object.

Parameters
----------
url : str

Returns
-------
dict
"""
stock_symbol = ["AAPL","TSLA"]
for symbol in stock_symbol:
print (symbol)
#Sending the API request
r = requests.get('https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/income-statement/symbol={stock_symbol}?limit=120&apikey={removed by me})
packages_JSON = r.json()
print(packages_JSON)
#Exporting the data into JSON file
with open('stocks_data321.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f: 
    json.dump(packages_JSON, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

Comment: Try copy the url in your get request, paste it in the browser and see if you get a response. If yes, instead of _r.json()_, do _r.text_ If you want async support to query multiple api at the same time, use [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable). python3 only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python requests with multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280094/python-requests-with-multithreading)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying multiple APIs iterativelly will take a lot of time. Consider using `theading` or `AsyncIO` to do requests simultaniously and speed up the process.

In a nutshell you should do something like this for each API:

```
import threading

for provider in [...]:  # list of APIs to query
    t = threading.Thread(target=api_request_function, args=(provider, ...))
    t.start()
```

However better read [this great article](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/#threading-objects) first to understand whats and whys of threading approach.