# Python Requests Discord Tag ID

Tags: python, discord

I wrote a spam program on discord by tagging it with python request. The code below is working, but it is sending messages one after the other, how can I send messages side by side.

```
token = input("Enter Token: ")
    print("----------------------------------------------------------")
    sunucuid = input("spam server id: ")
    print("----------------------------------------------------------")
    channelId = input("channel ıd: ")
    print("----------------------------------------------------------")
    with open ('users.txt','r') as dosya:
       for line in dosya.read().splitlines():
          for i in range(5): 
           mesaj = "<@"+line+">"
           headers = {"authorization": token}
           payload = {"content": mesaj}
           requests.post(f"https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channelId}/messages", headers = headers, data=payload)
```

Comment: you can use `threading`, `multiprocessing` or `asyncio` to run some code at the same time. And `reuqests` has even special modules to use it - ie. `requests-toobelt` and `httpx`

Comment: can you give examples with some codes?

Comment: find `httpx` and you will have example in documentation. OR documentation for [toolbelt](https://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/threading.html)

Comment: you may also find examples in similar questions - like [Python requests with multithreading - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280094/python-requests-with-multithreading)

Comment: when ı spam messages with multiprocessing it is spam second time one after the other,ı want spam messages in same line

Comment: you have to send single message to every process and it will send only one message

Comment: Can you explain it more clearly or give an idea how to do it?

Comment: every process has to run only one `requests.post()` with only one message but it seems you put all `for`-loop in process - so it runs again all messages. You needs loop outside process - `for one_message in list_of_messages: process(one_message)`

Comment: I do like this but "processs(one_message)" giving eror
`with open ('users.txt','r') as dosya:
              for one_message in dosya.read().splitlines(): processs(one_message)
              mesaj = "<@"+one_message+">"
              payload = {"content": mesaj}
              headers = {"authorization": token}
              processs = 
              requests.post(f"https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channelId}/messages",headers = headers, data=payload)`

Comment: don't run `open` inside `process` - you have to run only one `requests.post` in process. And this was only pseudo code - real code need `Thread(taget=process, args=(message,).start()`

Comment: like this  `dosya = requests.post('users.txt')
               for one_message in dosya.read().splitlines(): processs(one_message)
               mesaj = "<@"+one_message+">"
               payload = {"content": mesaj}
               headers = {"authorization": token}
               processs = requests.post(f"https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channelId}/messages", headers = headers, data=payload)
               thread(taget=processs, args=(mesaj,).start())`
    but giving error again

Comment: better see code in my answer because you create some big mitsakes in code. Why do you put filename in post - `requests.post('users.txt')` ? `Process` has to be function. You can't use `process = ... ` to create function. You have to learn how to use `threads`. Maybe find some tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it.

You can use `threading` to run every `requests.post` in separated thread like

```
import threading

def process(line, token):
    mesaj = "<@"+line+">"
    headers = {"authorization": token}
    payload = {"content": mesaj}
    requests.post(f"https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channelId}/messages", headers=headers, data=payload)

# --- main ---

token = input("Enter Token: ")
print("----------------------------------------------------------")

sunucuid = input("spam server id: ")
print("----------------------------------------------------------")

channelId = input("channel ıd: ")
print("----------------------------------------------------------")

all_threads = []

with open ('users.txt') as dosya:
    for line in dosya.read().splitlines():
        for i in range(5):
            t = threading.Thread(target=process, args=(line, token))
            t.start()
            all_threads.append(t)

# wait for end of all threads 

for t in all_threads:
    t.join()
```

Similar way works `multiprocessing`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\guven\Desktop\MASS TAG\main.py", line 52, in <module>
    for t in all_threads():
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
giving this error

Comment: sorry it has to be `:` instead of `()`. I fixed it.

Comment: it works like this
@test
one after another ı want side by side

Comment: I don't understand what you mean `side by side`. Maybe you means something different than I expect. I means `"run code (almost) at the same time"` But it never is ideal because CPU has to run hundreds threads and processes and some of them may have to wait few milliseconds - and you can't change it. But maybe you need to  create one string and send it as single message in single request. I don't understand it so I can't help you more.

Comment: so how can ı loop this code

Comment: you have all code with loop in answer. I don't understand what else you want to loop.

Comment: it spams only one time all ids ı want spam 1 or 3 times spam all ids

Comment: there is `for i in range(5):` so it should spam them 5 times.